# Posting wget html pages to Solr

Tags: solr, wget

How can I post html web pages to a Solr index when downloading them with wget? How could I modify the following example so that it gets indexed simultaneously? wget -P /var/myserver/archive http://www.somesite/products.html

I can't spot an obvious example in the Solr documentation and would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Apache Nutch](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial), which is an Open source web crawler.
You can provide Nutch with a base page and it will help you index the page as well as the links in it.
Nutch integrates with Solr so the pages would be indexed by Solr and be searchable.

However, if its just couple of pages with not Spider capabilities you can just download the html pages and feed it to solr through Client code.
Solr have HTML filters which will hep to extract content from this pages and index them as text.